# GCP compute engine wont restart - Resource unavailable in Europe zone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Any GCP expert to resolve this issue ?

I created a compute engine on GCP and it had some issue so I was forced to restart the instance and found that the instance resource is missing which is really a strange this to happen. Below is the exact error message I get.

I changed the machine type from n1-standard-1 to n1-standard-2 and again tried restarting it still dint work.

```
My First Project
A n1-standard-1 VM instance is currently unavailable in the europe-west2-c zone.
Alternatively, you can try your request again with a different VM hardware configuration or at a later time. For more information, see the troubleshooting documentation.
```

Same toast error message
[image: Same toast error message]

Comment: The error means that there is no VM to launch your instance onto. Options: 1) Select a different instance size (small instance sizes are the most popular). 2) Move the VM to a different region which can be a pain. 3) Wait until resources are available, such as the early morning or evening in your time zone.

Comment: I feel like that is a reliability issue, I had to restart my machine after a software update and this issue is going to cause a lot of down time. What's the best solution to this ? If the resource gets utilized how would I know which to pick from ?

Comment: Google offers reservations. If you don't do that, then you are subject to product/service availability. For more information, read this: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview The availability of services is a vendor issue, we cannot help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In public clouds like GCP, **shared hardware resources** will be used to run  our VMs. When you stop and start your VM, the resources will get **released and reattached**; as a result if there is any ongoing **resource shortage at Datacenters**, your VM’s resources will be allocated to another VM and if there aren’t sufficient resources available your VM will end up in a failed state.

To prevent this from happening in future, you should **[reserve your computational resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview)**, but for now the only way out of this is to take a snapshot of your VM and recreate it using a different machine type which is available and which is equivalent to the current machine type.

In your case, both n1-standard-1 and n1-standard-2 are not available. Try switching to a different compute engine series for creating the VM.

**Note:** Unfortunately, there isn't any solution or method available for the public to check these resource crunch situations. You need to contact the google support team who can fill you with more details on this issue.

Comment: FYI: you can edit the Compute Engine instance to change the machine type and then start it.

Comment: That is really help full, I was trying to understand if the resource is available or not, they could at least prompt about the availability during the instance creation, it rather tries to create and fails due to unavailability